# Play java application with jdk: deployment

Tags: java, deployment, playframework

I develop  a web app with using Play framework.
I develop a specific function which need jdk (I use jdk commands).
Could you advise me, where I can deploy this app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do package your app using following play command

```
play war myapp -o myapp.war
```

Once you get the war generated, you can deploy it on any app container like tomcat. 
Refere here for more options: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/deployment